# How can I get a field value from a document in firestore with typescript or javascript and put in a console.log()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these collections.

I need get a field value from "Protocolos finalizados" and put in a console.log().

Can someone help me, please?

I´m using node.js and typescript.

[image]

Below in my code I try to compare the value of fields from different collections and get a result that came from "Protocolos finalizados" and "Listagem de pagamento" collections.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
const serviceAccount = require('../sheets_updater_service_account.json')
const sheets = google.sheets('v4')
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore"
initializeApp()
const firestore = getFirestore()


module.exports.readAndUpdateAdministrativeSheet = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    // =========================== AUTENTICAÇÃO FIREBASE ===================================
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        key: serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    })

    await jwtClient.authorize()


    // ================= CONEXÃO COM A PLANILHA CRIAÇÃO DE FILTROS =========================
    const { data } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: 'google sheets id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        //range: `Listagem de pagamento!A2:X6`,
    })

    // ========= CRIAÇÃO DE BANCO DE DADOS DA COLEÇÃO LISTAGEM DE PAGAMENTO ================
    const generateDuplicities = data.values!.map(async row => {
        const [nome, cpf, numeroRequerimento, arbitramentoHonorários] = row
        firestore.collection("Listagem de pagamento").doc(numeroRequerimento).set({
            nome, cpf, numeroRequerimento, arbitramentoHonorários            
        })

        // =========================== DUPLICIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA ===================================        
        const duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = new Array()
        const resultduplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = firestore.collection('Protocolos finalizados') //1lGPC1UuxVRplJCVfAXAPWeigjgx1ETyx1OpdtCCJoXo (Pagamentos finalizados)
            .where("autosPF", "==", arbitramentoHonorários) // autosPF => Planilha Pagamentos finalizados  /  arbitramentoHonorários => Planilha de Criaão de filtros
            .where("cpf_PF", "==", cpf) // cpf_PF => Planilha Pagamentos finalizados  /  cpf => Planilha de Criação de filtros
        //const requerimento = firestore.collection('Protocolos finalizados').doc().collection('requerimento')
        const mesPagamento = firestore.collection('Protocolos finalizados').doc("mesPagamento")
        const resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = await resultduplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.get()
        if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size) {
            resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.forEach(doc => {
                if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size == 1) {
                    functions.logger.log("Foi encontrada " + `${resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size} ` + "duplicidade administrativa referente a pessoa " + `${nome}.`)
                    functions.logger.log(doc.id)
                    functions.logger.log(doc.id,'mesPagamento')
                    functions.logger.log(doc.data()) //NÃO MEXER
                    //functions.logger.log("Criação de filtros (Listagem de pagamento): " + `${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, "\nPagamentos finalizados (Protocolos finalizados): " + `${'requerimento'}: ${requerimento}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${mesPagamento}`)
                    // Requerimento e mesPagamento devem vir da planilha de pagamentos finalizados
                    duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.push(`${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, `${'requerimento'}: ${doc.id}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${mesPagamento}`)
                    functions.logger.log(duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges)
                } else if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size > 1) {
                    functions.logger.log("Foram encontradas " + `${resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size} ` + "duplicidades administrativa referente a pessoa " + `${nome}.`)
                    functions.logger.log(doc.id)
                    //functions.logger.log("Criação de filtros (Listagem de pagamento): " + `${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, "\nPagamentos finalizados (Protocolos finalizados): " + `${'requerimento'}: ${requerimento}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${mesPagamento}`)
                    // Requerimento e mesPagamento devem vir da planilha de pagamentos finalizados
                    duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.push(`${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, `${'requerimento'}: ${doc.id}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${mesPagamento}`)
                    functions.logger.log(duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges)
                } else if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size === 0) {
                    functions.logger.log('Não há duplicidades administrativas nesta lista')
                    console.log('Não há duplicidades administrativas nesta lista')
                }
            })
        }
    })
    await Promise.all(generateDuplicities)
})

exports.protocolosFinalizados = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        key: serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    })

    await jwtClient.authorize()

    const { data } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: 'google sheets id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        //range: `Protocolos finalizados!A406480:L406482`
    })

    data.values?.forEach(row => {
        const [requerimento, autosPF, cpf_PF, mesPagamento] = row
        firestore.collection("Protocolos finalizados").doc(requerimento).set({
            requerimento, autosPF, cpf_PF, mesPagamento
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and the specific challenge you have so that we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: Hello @MarkSchultheiss! I updated the question I asked, inserting all the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and replicated your Firebase data structure,

[image]

and you will be able to get a field value from your collection using this query:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, query, getDocs, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID"
});

const db = getFirestore();

var ref = query(collection(db, "test-data"));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(ref);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log("mesPagamento: ",  doc.data().mesPagamento);
});
```

And the output will be:

```
mesPagamento:  11/2019
mesPagamento:  12/2020
```

For more information, you may refer on [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). It's a good way to start learning Firestore queries.
There's also a guide on how to [perform simple and compound queries in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9).

Comment: Hello @RJC! I updated the question I asked, inserting all the code I'm using.
With your answer, I was getting errors because I´m importing getFirestore() from "firebase-admin/firestore" (i think i need this import).

Comment: @RodrigoFiadPasini,  can you also include the error/s when using the `getFirestore()`? Additionally, you can follow my code for the `initializeApp()` to include the `project-id`.

Comment: I tried again using your answr in my code, and now it´s working. Thank you soo much.